# how to achieve Gv.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(Gv_RowDataBound); in vb?

Tags: vb.net

how to achieve
Gv.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(Gv_RowDataBound); in vb?

Answer (score 0):

To bind an event in VB.NET, use the [AddHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) statement, like so:

```
AddHandler Gv.RowDataBound, AddressOf Gv_RowDataBound
```

To unbind, swap it for the the similar [RemoveHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xz97kac%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) statement.

Oh as a side note, VB automatically creates a `GridViewRowEventHandler` for you.

Hope that helps, Tom :)